SvelteKit / problems with loading from .svelte-components
I've got some problems with my loading-function.
So this is the current situation:
The projekt consists of these four main files:

data.js
Here are the information stored which should be displayed.
chain_one.svelte
This is the component which is linked in the data.js and should be displayed if needed
+page.server.js
Here is the load-function placed for loading the needed data from data.js
+page.svelte
For displaying the information strored

I don't know why but I am not able to display the linked .svelte-component. In the best case I got a Error-Message like Error: Failed to serialize promise while rendering and the information is "only" missing when opening the site. In the worst case I got a 500-Error-Message in the browser and nothing is displayed. (depence on what I tried).
Here is my current code which ended up in the Error-Message:
Error: Failed to serialize promise while rendering
data.js:
const chain_one = import('../svg/chain/chain_one.svelte');

export const chains = [
    {
        title: 'Chain One', 
        link: 'lib/images/Chain_one.png',
        svg: chain_one,
        callflow: [
            ....plenty other information an other chains...

+page.server.js:
import { chains } from '../../lib/components/data.js';

export async function load({ params }) {
    const resolvedChains = chains;
    const chain = resolvedChains.find(chain => chain.title === params.serviceketten); // this is for choosing the current selected chain

    if (!chain) throw error(404);

    console.log(chain);
    return {
        titel: chain.title,
        svg: chain.svg,
    };
}

+page.svelte:
<scale-card slot="card_right_top">
        <h3>Detailsansicht Servicekette {data.title}</h3>
        {#await data.svg}
            <p>Laden...</p>
        {:then component}
            {#if component}
                <svelte:component this={component.default} />
            {/if}
        {/await}
    </scale-card>

I tried severel things found on google.
For example changing the return:
return {
        svg: await chain.svg, <- doesn't have any effect
        svg: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chain.svg)) <- no error-message but only "[Objekt]" was displayed


You cannot return components from a server load function.
Either use a universal load function (which has to be able to execute on server and client) or do not try to send a component class in the first place.
If you use a universal load, make sure to either await the import or directly import the component rather than using a dynamic import:
import chain_one from '../svg/chain/chain_one.svelte';

If you need to use a server load function there are several options:

Do not use a Svelte component and just a plain SVG if you can.
These can be imported as text via a ?raw suffix.
Fully server-side render the component and return its HTML/CSS.
If the import already returns an SSR component, it can be rendered.
Return some kind of ID and resolve the component only on the client.
export const chains = [
    {
        title: 'Chain One',
        link: 'lib/images/Chain_one.png',
        svg: 'chain_one',
        ...

On page:
import chain_one from '../svg/chain/chain_one.svelte';

const svgs = {
    'chain_one': chain_one, // or dynamic import + {#await} if it should be lazy
    ...
};

<svelte:component this={svgs[data.svg]} />



